# Dreamhost DNS to AWS Route 53

Tags: domain-name-system, failover

I'm looking to setup DNS failover for config.webconverger.com and I think Route53 is the best option to get it going.

However I'm confused how to export the DNS zone from Dreamhost to Route 53, without typing in every subdomain into Route53's UI.

Am I missing a trick?

Comment: Amazon Route 53 is capable of [importing a zone file](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/rrs-changes-import-console.html), but as far as I can tell Dreamhost will not export one. You should contact Dreamhost before giving up, though.

Comment: I asked DreamHost about this ~6 months ago; **their support staff said they were unable to export a zone file**. I ended-up copy-pasting records from the control panel in an all-too-arduous process. At the time, I don't believe Route53 would import a zone (they do now!); if I was doing it today, I'd probably copy-paste the whole zone from the control panel, and 'massage' it into a zone file for import.

Comment: Sounds like another reason to avoid Dreamhost like the proverbial.

Comment: DreamHost doesn't do zone exports. That's one reason I use CloudFlare as my primary DNS instead, because they do exports and imports. It's a pain when DreamHost changes the server IPs on me, though. Lots of manual replacements ensue.